# Pivot providing invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to merge two tables of data together and then want to pivot the amounts by the table names they are from, however I get an invalid column error.

I have two databases with identical column names I wish to merge and identify, then pivot based on the table they are (A and B).

I am able to unify the tables OK, however when I try to pivot, it tells me "Measure" is an invalid column.

```
="SELECT TABLE1.ACCNT_CODE,TABLE1.PERIOD,TABLE1.REPORT_AMT, 'B' MEASURE FROM TABLE1

UNION ALL

SELECT TABLE2.ACCNT_CODE,TABLE2.PERIOD,TABLE2.REPORT_AMT, 'A' MEASURE FROM TABLE2

PIVOT  
(  
SUM(REPORT_AMT)  
FOR MEASURE IN ([A], [B])  
) AS PivotTable;
"
```

Ideally, I would like to see A and B as separate columns with the amounts in each column, so I can see the amount per account per period for A vs B, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

```
Select *
 From (
        SELECT TABLE1.ACCNT_CODE
              ,TABLE1.PERIOD
              ,TABLE1.REPORT_AMT
              , 'B' MEASURE 
        FROM  TABLE1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TABLE2.ACCNT_CODE
              ,TABLE2.PERIOD
              ,TABLE2.REPORT_AMT
              ,'A' MEASURE 
        FROM TABLE2
      ) src
PIVOT ( SUM(REPORT_AMT) FOR MEASURE IN ([A], [B])  ) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: @Dinklage5200 Happy to help.   You had a slight structure issue.